# Appending a list to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text-files

I'm trying to read a text file separated by kewords. I'm using a dictionary to organize the information corresponding to each section. For example, for the text file:

```
*VERTICES
1 0 0
2 10 0
3 10 10
4 0 10
*EDGES
1 1 2
2 1 4
3 2 3
4 3 4
```

has the `*EDGES` and `*VERTICES` sections. My goal is to produce a dictionary like:

```
dict = {'*VERTICES': [[0,0], [0,10], [10,0], [10,10]], '*EDGES': [[1,2], [1,4], [2,3], [3,4]]}
```

This is my code:

```
with open('c:/geometry.txt','r') as inputfile:
    xyz = []
    dic = {}
    key = None
    for line in inputfile:
        line = line.replace(',','')
        linelist = ' '.join(line.split())
        linelist = linelist.split(' ')
        if(linelist[0][0]=='*'):
            key = linelist[0]
            dic[key] = []
        else:
            for i in range(0,len(linelist)):
                string2float = float(linelist[i])
                xyz.append(string2float)
            dic[key].append(xyz)
            del xyz[:]

print(dic)
```

And this is the current output:

```
{'*VERTICES': [[], [], [], []], '*EDGES': [[], [], [], []]}
```

Emtpy, as you can see. I'm guessing that the erros is at the `dic[key].append(xyz)` line. What I'm I doing wrong? I noticed that if I try to append linelist instead (e.g. `dic[key].append(linelist)`), the code works fine, but I wont have my variables transformed from string to float.

Is there any way I can get it to work with the xyz (float) list? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's relevant to your current issue, but your double-splitting of `line` into `linelist` seems a bit silly. Why not just use `linelist = line.split()` and be done with it? The extra `join` and `split` exactly reverse one another.

Comment: Did you not get enough from your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679036/how-to-read-and-organize-text-files-divided-by-keywords. You can just change `linelist` to `list(map(float, linelist))` to convert them all to floats.

Comment: The reason they are all empty is because you a reusing the same `xyz` list and deleting its contents `del xyz[:]`. Just create a new `xyz = []` in the `else` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very last lines of your code are not doing what you want them to do:

```
        dic[key].append(xyz)
        del xyz[:]
```

You're appending a reference to your `xyz` list to the list in the dictionary, but they you're delting the list's contents. The `del` statement on the slice modifies the list in place, so the references stored in the dictionary will also see the empty list result afterwards.

In fact, all your empty inner lists in the dictionary are references to the same empty `xyz` list. What you probably want to do is to actually create a new list for `xyz`, rather than deleting its contents:

```
        dic[key].append(xyz)
        xyz = []
```

Or, better yet, use a list comprehension to build the new list with its contents and get rid of the `xyz` variable entirely:

```
    else:
        dic[key].append([float(num) for num in linelist])
```

Note that this will include all three values from your file in the inner dictionaries. If you only want two, you probably want to slice `linelist`.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're greatly overcomplicating this. Your code is very difficult to follow, due partly to cryptic variable names (what is `xyz`?). @Blckknght correctly identified the cause of the bug in your program. (In fact, I gave him/her an upvote.) The only thing I can contribute here is some working code:

```
d = {}

with open('c:/geometry.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('*'):
            key = line.strip()
            d[key] = []
        else:
            d[key].append(map(int, line.split()[1:]))
```

Comment: I guess I could use better variable names. The extra (splitting and joining) are there because in the original text file I also have commas and repeated blank spaces, and I wanted to get rid of them. I'm almost sure that there is a better way of doing it, but I'm just starting with Python. Thanks for your comment!